# In (a) broad range of

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Should "a" be used in the titular expression? I've found instances in which "a" used :

> This book presents a practical introduction to signal analysis techniques that are commonly used in a broad range of engineering areas such as biomedical engineering, communications, geophysics, speech, etc.

and those without "a" :

> KNN algorithm is used in broad range of classification problems such as: medical diagnosis, image processing, predicting of properties of amino acids sequences.

I think both are identical, however, could not prefer one over another.

Comment: The second one is not idiomatic English, any more than "presents practical introduction to" would be.

Comment: Well, "range" is a singular noun, so yes it should have the article "a" before it in written text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are not identical; the second is incorrect.  It would be correct if *range* was plural, ie.

> used in broad *ranges* of classification problems..

Otherwise, an article, "a", is required.